# Can you upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

1. Is it true that you can upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10 for free?
2. If so, how can you upgrade from windows 7 to windows 10?

Comment: What does your research tell you? What exactly does this have to do with Java?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Microsoft will make a download available which will update your installation to windows 10.

Note: this free upgrade will not remain free forever. Only for a limited time of 1 year, up until the 29th of July 2016.

After this, you *can* reinstall Windows 10, but only on a modern machine which uses UEFI (as the key will be embedded); however if you reset your BIOS or change the motherboard, you will need to purchase a Windows 10 licence in order to reactivate.